# how can I copy data validations from one spreadsheet to another using google script

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to write script that will get a cell that has Data validation from a control spreadsheet and add it to a location (same) in another spreadsheet.

I am using:

```
  var myCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('D4');
  var rule = myCell.getDataValidation();
```

but apparently the spreadsheet is not active during the script process so the rule is null.

Answer (score 0):

If you can check [this product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/pBDeCGqzlMI), it was answered there.

Also it was cited in one of the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619562/how-to-copy-data-validation-in-a-relative-way-specifically-list-from-range-wit) that this feature was currently not supported. But they gave a workaround to do it.

Copy the [sheet from the original post](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nx0z5TwZ7lGa5E1bkzcWNXMJKkPaygcom_vPy84PQME/edit?usp=sharing), then follow the steps below:

> 1. Select a range of cells across which you want to copy a data
>      validation rule, relatively
> 2. From the Validation+ custom menu, select the appropriate option (all
>      references relative, columns absolute, or rows absolute)
> 3. The validation of the upper-left cell will be copied to the rest of
>      the range

Also, if you would like to create from scratch, I've post the same script that was specified in the SO post:

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu
  (
    "Validation+",
    [
      {name: "Copy validation (all relative references)", functionName: "copyValidation"},
      {name: "Copy validation (relative rows, absolute columns)", functionName: "copyValidationColumnsAbsolute"},
      {name: "Copy validation (absolute rows, relative columns)", functionName: "copyValidationRowsAbsolute"}
    ]
  );
}

function copyValidation(rowsAbsolute, columnsAbsolute)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var dv = r.getDataValidations();
  var dvt = dv[0][0].getCriteriaType();
  if (dvt != SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE) return;
  var dvv = dv[0][0].getCriteriaValues();
  Logger.log(dvv);
  for (var i = 0; i < dv.length; i++)
  {
    for (var j = i ? 0 : 1; j < dv[0].length; j++)
    {

      dv[i][j] = dv[0][0].copy().withCriteria(dvt, [dvv[0].offset(rowsAbsolute ? 0 : i, columnsAbsolute ? 0 : j), dvv[1]]).build();
    }
  }
  r.setDataValidations(dv);
}

function copyValidationRowsAbsolute()
{
  copyValidation(true, false);
}

function copyValidationColumnsAbsolute()
{
  copyValidation(false, true);
}
```

Comment: I have found that this does not work across spreadsheets.  However, I did get it to work by making the sheet I am trying to move it to, ACTIVE.  If I was trying to move it to a totally different Spreadsheet, then I had to make that Spreadsheet and it's sheet ACTIVE.  I am sure there is a better way but this worked for me.